# getline seems to not working correctly

Tags: c++, fstream, getline

Please tell me what am I doing wrong here. What I want to do is this:
1.Having txt file with four numbers and each of this numbers has 15 digits:

```
std::ifstream file("numbers.txt",std::ios::binary);
```

I'm trying to read those numbers into my array:

```
  char num[4][15];
```

And what I'm thinking I'm doing is: for as long as you don't reach end of files write every line (max 15 chars, ending at '\n') into num[lines]. But this somewhat doesn't work. Firstly it reads correctly only first number, rest is just "" (empty string) and secondly file.eof() doesn't seems to work correctly either. In txt file which I'm presenting below this code I reached lines equal 156. What's going on?

```
                for (unsigned lines = 0; !file.eof(); ++lines)
                {
                    file.getline(num[lines],15,'\n');  
                }
```

So the whole "routine" looks like this:

```
int main()
{
std::ifstream file("numbers.txt",std::ios::binary);

char numbers[4][15];

            for (unsigned lines = 0; !file.eof(); ++lines)
            {
                file.getline(numbers[lines],15,'\n');// sizeof(numbers[0])
            }
}
```

This is contents of my txt file:

111111111111111
222222222222222
333333333333333
444444444444444

P.S.
I'm using VS2010 sp1

Comment: Are you serious? `getline` is not working correctly? Unbelievable!

Comment: @Vlad I'm just not sure, probably it's me who is doing something but I don't see where.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not use the eof() function! The canonical way to read lines is:

```
while( getline( cin, line ) ) {
    // do something with line
}
```

Comment: @Neil, and is there any particular reason for not using eof?

Comment: @Bruce: how about googling "safe bool idiom" before downvoting an answer to a question about a language you clearly don't understand well enough?
+1 to compensate, this is a spot on answer.

Comment: @Neil and the way you've showed somewhat doesn't work with my multidimensional array, I'm getting error "No instance of overloaded function matches the arguments list"

Comment: @smallB  Using eof() usually is an attempt to guess what the NEXT I/O will do, when actually it tells you what the PREVIOUS one did. As for it not working with your code, well there are a lot of reasons why that might not be the case. As you are reading char[]'s (once again why???) you want while( file.getline( ... ) ).

Comment: @Neil it doesn't work because as I've said I'm getting an error from IntelliSense telling me that this function cannot accept those params.

Comment: @Neil what I've figured out is that if I have a number with 15 digits I have to set my array to char arr[][**16**] and while reading line also **16** characters must be read. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`file.getline()` extracts 14 characters, filling in `num[0][0] .. num[0][13]`.  Then it stores a `'\0'` in `num[0][14]` and sets the `failbit` on `file` because that's what it does when the buffer is full but terminating character not reached.

Further attempts to call `file.getline()` do nothing because failbit is set.

Tests for `!file.eof()` return true because the eofbit is not set.

Edit: to give a working example, best is to use strings, of course, but to fill in your char array, you could do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("numbers.txt"); // not binary!
    char numbers[4][16]={}; // 16 to fit 15 chars and the '\0'
    for (unsigned lines = 0;
         lines < 4 && file.getline(numbers[lines], 16);
         ++lines)
    {
        std::cout << "numbers[" << lines << "] = " << numbers[lines] << '\n';
    }
}
```

tested on Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Comment: There is nothing to suggest it would encounter any sort of failure, so why would the `failbit` be set?

Comment: @rcollyer the failure in this case is the failure to perform the requested operation ("read a line")

Comment: I should have read a little further down. Makes me appreciate the `std::string` version of `getline` more.

Answer (score 1):

According to [ifstream doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/), reading stops either after n-1 characters are read or delim sign is found : first read would take then only 14 bytes.

It reads bytes : '1' (the character) is 0x41 : your buffer would be filled with 0x41 instead of 1 as you seem to expect, last character will be 0 (end of c-string)

Side note, your code doesn't check that lines doesn't go beyond your array.

Using getline supposes you're expecting text and you open the file in binary mode : seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to the following:

```
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    //no need to use std::ios_base::binary since it's ASCII data
    std::ifstream file("numbers.txt");

    //allocate one more position in array for the NULL terminator
    char numbers[4][16];

    //you only have 4 lines, so don't use EOF since that will cause an extra read
    //which will then cause and extra loop, causing undefined behavior
    for (unsigned lines = 0; lines < 4; ++lines)
    {
        //copy into your buffer that also includes space for a terminating null
        //placing in if-statement checks for the failbit of ifstream
        if (!file.getline(numbers[lines], 16,'\n'))
        {
            //make sure to place a terminating NULL in empty string
            //since the read failed
            numbers[lines][0] = '\0';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: from getline doc the terminating null should be added automatically, then you doing somewhat twice the same work, first you copy from file to temp and then you copy this same from temp to numbers. There MUST be better way!

Comment: -1: Wow, you put a lot of trust on nothing going wrong in `getline`.

Comment: Okay, I added some more safety features to the `getline` call

Comment: @smallB: I've shrunk the code down, but you'll definitely want to add a safety feature that terminates your strings should `getline` fail.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the '\n' in the end of the first like is not being considered, and remaining in the buffer. So in the next `getline()` it gets read.

Try adding a file.get() after each getline().

If one file.get() does not work, try two, because under the Windows default file encoding the line ends with '\n\r\' (or '\r\n', I never know :)